# Spark submit in cluster mode, exception in thread "main"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

My spark submit syntax is:
spark-submit --queue regular --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.locality.wait=5000000ms --num-executors 100 --executor-memory 40G job.py

And the exception happened after job run successfully for a while, which is:

```
Application diagnostics message: User application exited with status 1
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1635856758535_5228470 finished with failed status
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1150)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1530)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

More importantly, in the job.py script, there's no local file read or write. Only parquet read or write.

And I cannot even track the application UI as the application was closed because of the exception. If anyone else encountered similar issue and has any ideas, please advice any solutions. Thanks!

Comment: since you submitted the job with cluster mode, you need to collect driver’s log in order to figure out what the exact error

Comment: Hi @pltc. Thanks for your reply. Can you advise how to collect driver's log? Do I need to add a spark config for it?

Comment: if you have YARN as Resource manager, you can use `yarn logs` like [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#debugging-your-application)

Comment: For this issue, my best way of solving it for now is to run it in client mode and know the error exactly first...